# I get different result for the same keras model

Tags: python, keras

I trained a VGG16 with imagenet-weights to classfiy images with 4 classes.

Train data:3578 images belonging to 4 classes.
Validation data:894 images belonging to 4 classes

Each time i run the code, i get one of this two accuracy value. val_acc: 1.0000 in first run. val_acc: 0.3364 in second run.

Any explication for this? because the difference between the results is to much large.

```
    train_dir = 'C:/Users/ucduq/Desktop/output1/train'
    validation_dir = 'C:/Users/ucduq/Desktop/output1/val'

        training_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1./255,
        #rotation_range=90,
        #horizontal_flip=True,
       # vertical_flip=True,
        #shear_range=0.9
        #zoom_range=0.9

        )

    validation_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

        IMAGE_WIDTH=150
        IMAGE_HEIGHT=150
    BATCH_SIZE=32
    input_shape=(150,150,3)

    training_generator = training_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        class_mode="categorical")
    validation_generator = validation_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        class_mode="categorical",
        shuffle=False)


    from keras.applications import VGG16

    vgg_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                      include_top=False,
                      input_shape=(150, 150, 3))


    model = models.Sequential()


    model.add(vgg_conv)

    ### Add new layers
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer='adam',metrics=["accuracy"])

results = model.fit_generator(training_generator, steps_per_epoch=training_generator.samples/training_generator.batch_size, 
                                  epochs=100,
                                  callbacks=callbacks,
                                  validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=28)

    first run:

    Epoch 100/100

    111/110 [==============================] - 17s 152ms/step - loss: 1.3593 - acc: 0.3365 - val_loss: 1.3599 - val_acc: 0.3364


    second run:

    Epoch 100/100

    111/110 [==============================] - 18s 158ms/step - loss: 1.9879e-06 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 5.2915e-06 - val_acc: 1.0000
```

Comment: Too few information. You better provide all code you use to train. What do you mean by exp_1 or 2? How did you pre-process. Given just these few line of code is impossible to tell anything.

Comment: i have added the entire code. I mean with exp_1 and 2: first run and second run.

Comment: The difference is because, you are not using the same validation data for both the cases. You have rescale turned on for validation data. Ideally your validation data should not have any data augmentation. If you want the validation data to be augmented as well, seed the random augmentation process across runs. However the recommendation is no augmentation on validation data

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your data has a class that is 33% of the entire set? If that true, what happen in the `first run:` is the model didn't learn anything at all(`acc: 0.3365`).

This might because of incorrect using of data-augmentation, if the commented lines are what you use in the first run then they are the culprits.

The
 `#shear_range=0.9` and 
 `#zoom_range=0.9`
is too much, only one of this means that you discord 90% of each image so the model doesn't learn anything.